# How to correctly describe the type of custom Record?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have custom class Record. It can be initialized with dict.
Can I describe my class with typing so that the IDE understands the presence of these fields in the Record?
Example:

```
rec = Record({'a':1})
rec.Get('a') # i'd like autocomplete in this place
```

Comment: can you show a example of how the `Record` class looks? and what are you exactly asking for? do you want type hints for the argument, or the `Get` function?

Comment: Record is python wrapper for C++ custom realisation. for type hints I use *.pyi stubs.
I want typehint for result or rec.Get('a') and autocomplete in IDE(I use Pycharm) when I write rec.Get('

Comment: I have not yet found an IDE that has a good understanding of which strings are valid and which are not. How can the IDE know that `'a'` is valid, but `'b'` is not, without executing your code?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch there is actually [Literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) that can do that.

Comment: @vivax this is only valid if the value set is known ahead of execution. I understood this question as "I type `rec = Record({'a':1})` and now PyCharm should know that `'a'` is a valid parameter to `rec.Get`". If that key is always `'a'`, then `Literal` is indeed a good choice.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch ah I see, hm well then idk. I think the best you can do then is what I suggested in my answer, but that only checks the type and not the actual content. but type hints should really only check, well types, checking the content should be up to the code it self

Comment: @vivax I agree. If your answer solves his problem, that's great. Type hinting is nice, but I don't think autocompletion of strings is possible in any Python IDE.

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved using [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) and [Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic)

we define 2 type vars, one for the key and one for the value. this is actually very similar to how a dict would actually be type-hinted.

```py
from typing import Dict, TypeVar, Generic

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")

class Record(Generic[K, V]):
    def __init__(self, val: Dict[K, V]) -> None: ...
    def get(self, key: K) -> V: ...
```

also if the key should always be a string you can just use `str` instead of `K`

```py
from typing import Dict, TypeVar, Generic

V = TypeVar("V")

class Record(Generic[V]):
    def __init__(self, val: Dict[str, V]) -> None: ...
    def get(self, key: str) -> V: ...
```